# How to use SOAP 1.2(request and response) in windows forms

Tags: vb.net, soap

I have never worked with SOAP but now i need to use it to get a XML file or CSV file with a lot of products.

I have searched the internet for some examples and found some but i still don't understand how to use it.
Am i wright that it just sends a XML file to a server and you get back a XML file with the data.

Do i really need to install this so that it works: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11413

And i need to implement it in a windows forms application.

Hope someone can help me with a good tutorial.

Comment: You don't need a tutorial. Just use WCF. Use "Add Service Reference" to access the service. See "[How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/)"

Comment: Tanx guys now i can give it a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to manually write all the code to do the SOAP communication yourself.  The .NET framework and visual studio provide tools to automatically build custom client classes that mimic the interface of the SOAP service, and perform all of the SOAP communication for you.  You don't need to install anything special, you just need to right-click on your project in the IDE and choose to add a Web Reference, or a Service Reference.